# Observable object field as query parameter in firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Auth service and a query service in angular.

The Auth service is responsible for logging in and keep track of a user object (observable)

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireAuth, AngularFireAuthModule} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreModule} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {User} from '../models/user';
import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

    user: Observable<User>;

    constructor(private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth, private fireStore: AngularFirestore) {
        this.user = this.fireAuth.authState.pipe(
            switchMap(user => {
                if (user) {
                    return this.fireStore.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
                } else {
                    return of(null);
                }
            }));
    }
}
```

In my query service I would like to fetch some documents based on the logged-in user id. That's why I added the authService as constructor parameter in the query service (probably not the best approach).

Querying the documents would happen like this:

```
this.data = this
              .fireStore
              .collection<Blimp>(
                  'blimps',
                  ref => ref.where('userIdTo', '==', ??ID_FROM_OBSERVABLE??)
              )
              .valueChanges()
              .pipe(map(collection => {
                  return collection.map(b => {
                      let blimp = new Blimp();
                      blimp.fileLocation = b.fileLocation;

                      return blimp;
                  });
              }));
```

As you can see I struggle to get the ID into that function because we are working with an observable.

My question is, what is the best approach here?

I was trying the following, but could not get it to work

```
this.blimps = this
              .fireStore
              .collection<Blimp>(
                  'blimps',
                  ref => ref.where('userIdTo', '==', this.authService.user.pipe(map((user) => user.userId)))
              )
              .valueChanges()
              .pipe(map(collection => {
                  return collection.map(b => {
                      let blimp = new Blimp();
                      blimp.fileLocation = b.fileLocation;

                      return blimp;
                  });
              }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to switchMap off your user id observable:

```
const userId$ = this.authService.user.pipe(map((user) => user.userId));

this.blimps = userId$.pipe(
                switchMap(userId => 
                  this
                    .fireStore
                    .collection<Blimp>(
                      'blimps',
                      ref => ref.where('userIdTo', '==', userId)
                    )
                    .valueChanges()
                    .pipe(map(collection => {
                      return collection.map(b => {
                        let blimp = new Blimp();
                        blimp.fileLocation = b.fileLocation;
                        return blimp;
                      });
                    })))
                );
```

this way, you switch into your firestore observable upon receiving the userId, and you'll be able to feed your userId into your firestore observable. Also, you will automatically cancel and reswitch everytime the userID changes.

Comment: For some reason, I have the feeling that the switchMap is not for this use case when I watch other examples. Maybe you can explain more in detail how it works in this use case, as with your text it's not totally clear to me.

Comment: switchMap is probably what you do want. When a new value comes from the source (userId in this case) it will cancel its previous firestore subscription and switch into a new one with the new use id. If for some reason you want to maintain firestore subscriptions for all userIds that come through at once, then use mergeMap instead. But typically you only want to be subscribed to one users data at a time.